# Asp.net core 2.0 remote testing and ef core mocking

Tags: sqlite, testing, asp.net-core-2.0, entity-framework-core

I am developing web api(s) for an android app client. Now the developer of the client, wants a way to test web api(s) without getting the real data corrupt. So now I am thinking of something like unit testing and database (ef core) mocking in that except the requests are remote and stateless; so every time the client app requests for data or changing it, the database should remember the last things.

From the [docs of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/), there are two ways to do this on unit testing:

- [SQLite in-memory mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite)
- [The InMemory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory)

But the thing is that those are volatile and from one request to another request they will be refreshed. So I think SQLite (normal mode - file mode), or using SQLServer with different connection string will be a good solution. Now there are some questions:

1. Is this a good idea or there is one better?
2. If it is good, then how should I implement it?
3. Is it good to add a header in the request?
4. On the server-side code where should I tell the ef to use testing database?

Comment: Assuming that using another connection string is a good solution, I have changed my question to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893073/asp-net-core-2-0-conditional-service-or-conditional-connection-string.