# Asp.net core 2.0 conditional service or conditional connection string

Tags: service, asp.net-core, http-headers, startup

I am developing web api(s) using Asp.net core 2.0. Now the thing I need is to use different connection strings which will be specified in the headers of the user.

I have previously seen this (not directly about this question):

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Headers["Authorization"]))
            {
                if (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
                {
                    var token = context.Request.QueryString.Value
                        .Split('&')
                    .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Contains("authorization"))?.Split('=')[1];

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                    {
                        context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new[] { $"Bearer {token}" });
                    }
                }
            }
            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

But how should I change the connection string in a way like this?

Am I going in the right direction?

### Update

I am looking for a middle ware like this:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(context.Request.Headers["TestMode"]) && context.Request.Headers["TestMode"] == true)
            {
                // TODO Change the connection string here
            }
            await next.Invoke();
        });
```

But don't know what to put in the TODO.

Comment: When you say 'connection string', are you talking about a database connection string? Because this is usually what 'connection string' refers to in the .NET world.

Comment: Yes absolutly. I was first thinking of add condition checking over services.AddDbContext to pass different database connection strings to that. But the thing was that is gets called once during server startup not every cleint request.

Comment: `different connection strings which will be specified in the headers of the user` - sounds ominous. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Assume that I have 2 databases and I want the client to choose which one he wants to work with (in every request).